# Module export returns undefined when returning value from database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and Express but I am stuck on the `module.export` function. Here is my code:

**list.js**

```js
exports.getCategory = function () {
    var sql = 'select * from categories';
    db.query(sql,function(error,rows){
        if(error){
            console.log('some error occured %s',error);
            return;
        }else{
            return rows;
        }
    });
}
```

I have a global SQL connection as database. I am not posting that connection now. While I use list.js in my app.js it prints undefined

**app.js**

```js
const list = require('./lib/list') 

console.log(list.getCategory)
```

I get undefined here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens if you try to log `list` out? your code looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with little effort i finally solved it was and callback error i needed a callback function here is the corrected code
**list.js**

```
exports.getCategory = function (callback) {
var sql = 'select * from categories';
db.query(sql,function(error,rows){
    if(error){
        console.log('some error occured %s',error);
        return;
    }else{
        callback(rows);
    }
});
}
```

**app.js**

```
const list = require('./lib/list') 

list.getCategory(function(result){
 console.log(result);

})
```

Comment: well, you just did not described your problem right. You don't call getCategory in your original question text.

Comment: _"I get undefined here"_ where _here_ is `console.log(list.getCategory)`. That's only possible when `list` has no `getCategory` property/method which is completely different to `list.getCategory()` returning `undefined` which is then the link in my comment...

Comment: @oniondomes console.log(list.getCategory) what is this if i have not called the function

Comment: it's logging the function itself rather than its result. if you want to output the result you write list.getCategory(); as you clearly do in the answer you gave.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for the link it helped me to understand asynchronous and synchronous  and i figure out whats wrong

Comment: @oniondomes yes but callback function is needed in order to get the result

Comment: but you need to call the function in order to get the result. you never stated you need the result, not the function itself. I understand that you got the solution you wanted, but the question was misleading

Answer (score 0):

require needs a file name (including ".js" extension), unless the file name is index.js - in which case, just the dir name would do. So you need to specify

```
const list = require('./lib/list.js')
```

Assuming list.js is inside the lib folder, and the lib folder is at the same level as app.js

There seems to be one more issue. "db.query" call is asynchronous. So by the time, console.log is done in app.js, the results may not be available. So you have to account for that. If "db.query" can return a Promise (instead of a callback) - you can return the promise and in "app.js" do a log on ".then" of the promise.

EDIT:

Since it is list.getCategory and not list.getCategory (), the asynchronous call has not been made - so async is not the problem. Thanks @oniondomes for pointing this out.

Comment: if this was the problem then it would have produced an error

Comment: how is that a asynchronicity problem? OP never calls this function. He just wants to get an access to it.